Can two compact Hausdorff spaces have the same convergent sequences?
In a lecture that I attended a few days ago, the lecturer seemed to indicate that given a compact Hausdorff space $(X,\tau)$, if we know exactly which sequences in $X$ that are convergent and if we know what all convergent sequences in $X$ converge to, then we can recover the topology $\tau$. In other words, if $(X,\tau)$ and $(X,\tau')$ are compact Hausdorff spaces such that given a sequence $(x_n)_{n\in\omega}$ in $X$ and some point $x\in X$, $x_n\to x$ in $(X,\tau)$ if and only if $x_n\to x$ in $(X,\tau')$, then $\tau=\tau'$. I have tried to prove this on my own, but I have not really gotten anywhere. Does anyone know how this can be done? Or, in case it is false, does anyone know a counterexample?
In a compact Hausdorff space $X$, subsets of $X$ are closed if and only if they are compact, so I have tried to use the information about which sequences that converge in $X$ to say something about the closed/compact sets in $X$. I have also tried to use the following fact: If $\tau$ and $\tau'$ are two topologies on $X$ such that
$$\forall A\subseteq X:\operatorname{cl}_\tau(A)\subseteq\operatorname{cl}_{\tau'}(A),$$
then $\tau'\subseteq\tau$. However, so far, I have not been able to make any of this work. I am very grateful for any help!

No, this is not true. Let $X$ be an infinite compact Hausdorff space such that the only convergent sequences are eventually constant. Note that these sequences are convergent with respect to all topologies and they only converge to their eventual constant value for $T_1$ topologies.
An example of such $X$ is $\beta\mathbf N\setminus \mathbf N$.
Then let $f\colon X\to X$ be an arbitrary discontinuous bijection (if $X$ is Hausdorff and not discrete, then there is such a bijection: start by fixing a set which is not closed and does not contain at least two points of $X$ and move a point in its closure, then extend arbitrarily). Let $X'$ be $X$ with the topology given by pulling back the topology on $X$ via $f$.
Then it is easy to see that $X$ and $X'$ have the same convergent sequences (with the same limits), but they are not the same.
Mind, if you assumed that the topologies are sequential (e.g. first-countable, e.g. metrisable), or you took into account arbitrary nets, not just sequences, then the claim would be true (because in the former case, the closure is the sequential closure, and in the latter case, the closure of any set is the set of all limits of convergent nets from that set). Compactness is not necessary.

Thank you for the reply! This seems to make sense to me. Do you think the statement would be true if we, in addition to what I said, required that $(X,\tau)$ and $(X,\tau')$ are not homemorphic? That is, could it be that compact Hausdorff spaces are determined up to homeomorphism by convergent sequences + their corresponding limits?

@Jon: No, I don't think that's true, either. For a counterexample, it suffices to find two non-homeomorphic compact Hausdorff spaces of the same cardinality with the property that all convergent sequences are eventually constant. I think $\beta\mathbf N\setminus \mathbf N$ and $\beta\omega_1\setminus \omega_1$ should probably work.

@tomasz: I think it is still unknown, whether $\beta \mathbb N \setminus \mathbb N$ and
$\beta \omega_1 \setminus \omega_1$ are never homeomorphic, see here, problem 36.
In fact, I think it is even considered to be the most important open problem about $\beta \mathbb N$.

Moreover, the cardinality of $\beta \mathbb N \setminus \mathbb N$ and $\beta \omega_1 \setminus \omega_1$ can be different!

But $\beta \mathbb N$ and $\beta \mathbb N \setminus \mathbb N$ would be examples.

@Ulli: Right. For some reason, I thought that you need to take away $\mathbf N$ to get no convergent sequences. Thanks for the correction!
